# Is it possible get a summary of programmer activity on Cloud 9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide, cloud9

In a collaborative development project on Cloud 9 IDE, is it possible to get some stats on programmer activity?  Similar to GitHub showing the number of commits / date, I would like to see activity stats on Cloud9.

Even the number of hours logged on or something would be good.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: do you want to do it programmatically? :)

Comment: not really, just would like to be able to view a report or a visual representation of activity by each programmer in the group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  wakatime plugin, which is provided by https://wakatime.com/.
See https://github.com/wakatime/c9-wakatime for instructions for installing it